# How to make ChaiJS 'expect' function available in all files inside NodeJS 'test' folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, truffle

I'm using Truffle which has Mocha & Chai included by default.

File tree:

```
├── test
│   ├── ManagedWallet.js
│   ├── AnotherTest.js
│   └── AndAnotherTest.js
└── truffle.js
```

This is one of my test file:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var managedWallet = artifacts.require("./ManagedWallet.sol");

contract('ManagedWallet', function(accounts) {

  it("belongs to customer's account address", async function(){
    var contract         = await managedWallet.deployed();
    var customer_account = accounts[1];
    var owner            = await contract.owner.call();

    expect(owner).to.equal(customer_account);
  });

});
```

Since I have a lot of test files inside the `test` folder, I need to put that `var expect = require('chai').expect;` line in all the test files.

Is there a way for me to make that `expect` function available globally without needing me to have that `var expect = require('chai').expect;` line in all my test files?

I tried putting `var expect = require('chai').expect;` line inside truffle.js file (above `module.exports`) but it didn't work and I got `ReferenceError: expect is not defined` error when I ran the tests.

Example of my truffle.js file (located in the root folder of the project):

```
module.exports = {

  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // match any network
    }
  }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my [**`.mocharc.json`**](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs) file that enables this:

```json
{
  "spec": "src/**/*.test.ts",
  "require": ["esm", "ts-node/register", "chai/register-assert", "chai/register-expect", "chai/register-should"],
  "file": "./test-setup.cjs",
  "recursive": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from [GitHub](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/1140#issuecomment-368524913) (thanks @keithamus).

```
require('chai/register-expect');

//... rest of code
expect(...)
```

My truffle.js looks like:

```
require('chai/register-expect');

module.exports = {
  // the truffle configs
}
```

And, using `expect` inside my test files no longer throwing any errors.